# Need New Div for Each Item in Object by Key and Render Values by Key

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, reduce

I'm trying to render ingredients/toppings by category for each item in my order app.
I have an object for each item that has an array of ingredients.  I was able to use reduce to group the ingredients by category but when I render it out, I can't loop through the array of ingredients.  I get undefined or just the generic [object].

I'm using Object.entries.map which gives me a new div for each category but I can't get the item name and cost.  I tried looping through the values and saving it to a variable, but I get undefined when I try to use it.  Here's my code:

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    } else {
      acc[key].push(obj);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

menuArray.forEach((item) => {
  const groupedByCategory = groupBy(item.ingredients, "category");

  const resultsToRender = Object.entries(groupedByCategory).map(
    ([key, value]) => {
      let valItem = value.forEach((val) => {
        return val.item;
      });
      return `
            <div>
                <h2>${key}</h2>
                <p>${valItem}</p>
            </div>
        `;
    }
  );

  document.getElementById("toppings-list").innerHTML += resultsToRender;
});
```

Here's a link to the codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/group-by-cat-object-arrays-33zrdd?file=/src/index.js:40-758

Comment: try [changing](https://codesandbox.io/s/group-by-cat-object-arrays-forked-5qr142) `forEach` to `map` in `let valItem = value.forEach((val) => {`. There's no return value when you use `.forEach`

Comment: @shrys thank you so much!!!  I have been going crazy trying to figure out why it wasn't working.  I completely forgot .forEach doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

just as suggested by @shrys

```js
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    } else {
      acc[key].push(obj);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

menuArray.forEach((item) => {
  const groupedByCategory = groupBy(item.ingredients, "category");

  const resultsToRender = Object.entries(groupedByCategory).map(
    ([key, value]) => {
-     let valItem = value.forEach((val) => {
-       return val.item;
-     });
+     let valItem = value.map(val => val.item)
      return `
            <div>
                <h2>${key}</h2>
                <p>${valItem}</p>
            </div>
        `;
    }
  );

  document.getElementById("toppings-list").innerHTML += resultsToRender;
});
```

however one caveat is that in pure javascript array will only display as `Array...` so you will need to add `.join`

```js
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    } else {
      acc[key].push(obj);
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

menuArray.forEach((item) => {
  const groupedByCategory = groupBy(item.ingredients, "category");

  const resultsToRender = Object.entries(groupedByCategory).map(
    ([key, value]) => {
-     let valItem = value.forEach((val) => {
-       return val.item;
-     });
+     let valItem = value.map(val => val.item).join(', ')
      return `
            <div>
                <h2>${key}</h2>
                <p>${valItem}</p>
            </div>
        `;
    }
- )
+ ).join('\n')
  document.getElementById("toppings-list").innerHTML += resultsToRender;
});
```

Comment: thank you for this!  That was going to be my next hurdle so I appreciate your help!